# Fade In String Characters with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, delay, fadein

Here is my code. For some reason the entire String fades in at one time instead of each individual character. My console.log shows the characters are being executed one by one. Why is the entire string fading in at one time? Shouldn't the statement within the for loop execute for each character?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      string = " David";
      for(i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        $('#fadeIn').append(string[i]).delay(1000).hide().fadeIn(1000);
        console.log(string[i]);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fadeIn" style="color: #000"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appends the string, then all the animation runs

Comment: Like this? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ujm3/1/)**.  [Similar Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074399/what-to-choose-for-typewriter-effect-in-javascript)

Comment: Completely understood Mark. Shouldn't it append the String with one character, then do the animation for the character, then carry out the same operations for each character thereafter?

Comment: Shivam, that works and makes sense, however I am wondering why my particular code doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Please see my answer for a cleaner solution and explanation

Comment: @David, you cant just append the each letter at once, you need to create at `setInterval` method that appends each letter separately. Coop also has it done correctly.

Comment: @DavidKagawa-Aguirre - to answer your question, no the characters are appended (fast) and the animation occur on the appended string.  You would need to "trap" that animation event completion or try to "avoid" it with timing, then add the next letter. Several ways to do that, I have put one example within an answer which lets the animation control the timing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the individual letters to fade in, they need to be DOM elements.

```
$(function() {
  var string = " David";
  var q = jQuery.map(string.split(''), function (letter) {
    return $('<span>'+letter+'</span>');
  });

  var dest = $('#fadeIn');

  var c = 0;
  var i = setInterval(function () {
    q[c].appendTo(dest).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    c += 1;
    if (c >= q.length) clearInterval(i);
  }, 1000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bGsa3/5/

Comment: Here it is a little cleaner, and it gets rid of all the spans when it's done with the effect. http://jsfiddle.net/bGsa3/6/

Answer (score 2):

The for loop is executing the delay, append and fade in on all letters at once, so they will show at the same time. You want to do this with a setInterval instead:

```
var string = "David",
stringCount = 0;

setInterval(function(){
  $('#fadeIn').append(string[stringCount]);
  stringCount += 1;
},1000);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bGsa3/

Comment: Works great, however it's infinite. I fixed the infinite issue, but I am trying to figure out how I would fadeIn each character without fadingIn the entire string as each character is fading In.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this for a bit, and believe this would be better served with `$.Deferred()`
This allows the animation to be whatever you want, and if you change that, it does not impact the rest - the animation controls the timing, firing "done" and starting the next letter when it completes by triggering the custom event.

Nothing fancy, just does what you asked.

Simple markup:

```
<div id="animator"></div>
```

For example:

```
var myString = " Freddy The Mark";
var i = 0;  // used to iterate the string, could be done other ways
var myEffect = function (c) {
    return $("#animator").append(c).fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(1);
};
$("#animator").on("show", function () {
    var c = myString[i];
    $.when(myEffect(c)).done(function () {
        i++;
        if (i < myString.length) {
            $('#animator').trigger('show');
        } else {
            $("#animator").show();//show it when we are done
        }
    });
});
$('#animator').trigger('show'); //get started by firing the custom event handler
```

Put it all together in a sample:  http://jsfiddle.net/N8eRN/1/