# Jquery fade in letters one at a time

Tags: jquery

Jquery fade in letters one at a time. It fades in all at once.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#html1').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
```

Would i have to split the string or what??

Comment: can u provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214066/fade-in-string-characters-with-jquery

Comment: this is what you're looking for, http://jsfiddle.net/bGsa3/5/ [FIRST RESULT IN GOOGLE]

Answer (score 0):

```
To get the individual letters to fade in, they need to be DOM elements.

var string = $('#html1').html();  
 $('#html1').html("");  
  var q = jQuery.map(string.split(''), function (letter) {

    return $('<span>'+letter+'</span>');
  });

  var destination = $('#html1');

  var c = 0;

  var i = setInterval(function () {

    q[c].appendTo(destination).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    c += 1;

    if (c >= q.length) clearInterval(i);
  }, 1000);
```